# Closed formula Fourier transform of complex exponential

Tags: fourier-analysis

Is there a closed formula for the Fourier transform of the function
\begin{equation}
f(t) = e^{2\pi i \sqrt{1-t^2}},
\end{equation}
where the square root for $|t|>1$ is $i \sqrt{t^2-1}$. This function emerges in Fourier optics.

Comment: How do you define the square root for $|t|>1$?

Comment: I added the definition.

Comment: This would give exponential growth at infinity. Are you sure about the sign?

Comment: Good point. It had to be the decaying function